# Splitting a string into two new strings

Tags: c#

I'm trying to split a string into two and store it into two new strings named username and location.

The incoming string contains

```
PUT /605226\r\n\r\nis being tested\r\n
```

I would like to extract `605226` as the username and `is being tested` as the location.

What would be the best way to do this?

Here is the code I want to implement it in, I cant use string arrays btw, Ive tried it/

```
else if (message.StartsWith("PUT /"))
{
  message.Replace("PUT /", "");
  
  username = "";
  location = "";
  
  if (UID.ContainsKey(username.Trim()))
  {
    sw.WriteLine(username);
    UID[username] = location;
    sw.WriteLine($"HTTP/0.9 200 OK\r\nContent-Type: text/plain\r\n\r\n");
  }
  else
  {
    sw.WriteLine(username);
    UID.Add(username, location);
    sw.WriteLine($"HTTP/0.9 200 OK\r\nContent-Type: text/plain\r\n\r\n");
  }
  sw.Flush();
}
```

Comment: Typical [XY problem](https://xyproblem.info/). What sort of application is this? Where does `"PUT /605226\r\n\r\nis being tested\r\n"` come from? It looks like an HTTP method, URL path and possibly body. There are definitely better ways to parse a request than this.

Comment: wow , you still at this? I assumed you had all this sorted out. You really need to post a question that shows the generic syntax of your input messages and what you need out, rather than posting each new message and asking how to decode it

Answer (score 0):

Why not use Regex?

```cs
Regex rx = new Regex(@"\/(\d*)\r\n\r\n(.*)\r\n");
MatchCollection matches = rx.Matches(message);
    
if (matches.Count < 1) {
    // not matched, can't extract username or location
}
        
string username = matches[0].Groups[1].Value;
string location = matches[0].Groups[2].Value;

// From here on, username will be '605226' and location 'is being tested'
```

This assumes the following:

- `username` will be a number and will go after a `/`.
- `\r\n\r\n` separates the `username` from the `location`.
- `message` ends with `\r\n`.

Answer (score -1):

How about…

```
else if (message.StartsWith("PUT /"))
    {

    username = message.Split('/')[1].Split('\r')[0];

    location = message.Split('\n')[2].Split('\r')[0];

}
```

Comment: But then `username` is going to be `"605226\r\n\r\nis being tested\r\n"` and `password` (which really should be `location`) will be `"\r\nis being tested\r\n"`

Comment: Good point. Will amend @Xerillio